# How to fix csv string format

Tags: sed, ipsec

I have line of `ipsec statusall <conn_name>` output. Depends on traffic flow it could be:

```
sr_mesh_aws_22{10}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/MODP_1024, 0 bytes_i, 0 bytes_o, rekeying in 32 minutes
```

sometimes:

```
sp_mesh_6_7{8}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128, 336  bytes_i, 336  bytes_o (4 pkts, 15s ago), rekeying disabled
```

or:

```
sr_mesh_aws_21{24}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96, 59189 bytes_i (469 pkts, 0s ago), 128238 bytes_o (431 pkts, 0s ago), rekeying in 32 minutes
```

String format:

```
conn_name{id}: algorithm, traffic in info, traffic out info, rekeying info
```

Everything would be easy parsable, but when the traffic start flow, extra information appears in the `traffic in info` or `traffic out info` fields between `(...)`. Moreover there are 2 fields separated by the same `,`!

How to replace all `,` to `;` inside all `(...)` if such exist?

preferable simple shell tools: sed/awk/...

Comment: Why don't you use [vici](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Vici) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example you show, a quick hack would be

- not to replace `,` within `(...)`
- but to replace `pkts,` with `pkts;`

giving :

```
echo "sr_mesh_aws_21{24}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96, 59189 bytes_i (469 pkts, 0s ago), 128238 bytes_o (431 pkts, 0s ago), rekeying in 32 minutes" | sed 's/pkts,/pkts;/g'
```

NB : the `echo ...` part is just to simulate your command output.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no nested parentheses as you didn't say that, then with `sed`:

```
sed ':repeat s/\(([^,)]*\),\([^)]*)\)/\1;\2/;t repeat' infile
```

Comment: Could you tell why do you use `:repeat` and `t repeat` combination instead of `s/../../g` option? Whats the difference?